# Spacy Named Entity Recognition Issue

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to tag ORG's from a bunch of text I am parsing through

What I have so far is as follows:

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

file = open("C:\\sample.txt")

doc = nlp(file.read())
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents])
```

Now, my result prints all possible tags, I just want it to print ORGs instead. Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X.label_` holds the name of the entity, so all you need is add a condition to only return those tuples where `X.label_` equals `ORG`:

```
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc.ents if X.label_ == "ORG"])
#                                           ^------------------^
```